# Sql Server 2008 not reporting compile errors for missing objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 doesn't always report a compile error when a stored procedure references an object that doesn't exist. Is there a way to cause it to always report errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option was suggested to Microsoft in 2005:

- [Microsoft Connect: Ability to disable or workaround deferred name resolution](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127152/ability-to-disable-or-workaround-deferred-name-resolution#tabs)

Apparently, there is still no option yet to get an error when a stored procedure that references an undefined object is created.

Erland Sommarskog, an SQL Server MVP had proposed one solution in the following article:

- [Ideas for SET STRICT_CHECKS ON: The End of Deferred Name Resolution](http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html#killDNR)

Answer (score 1):

I spotted this post and may able to suggest another option to help work-around deferred name resolution issues.

Using **SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON** , we then invoked an EXEC call to each stored procedure which instructed SQL Server to report estimates on resource usage for each statement, but not actually run the procedure. (NB: you also do not need to specify parameters passed to stored procedure).

if there were any missing tables etc, these would be captured and reported as Invalid objects.

More details on **SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON** found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187735.aspx).